# Incompatible pointer types sending 'int' to parameter of type 'va_list' (aka 'char')

Tags: ios, nsstring, char, arguments

I have a simple yet frustrating problem.

I have this line in my app:

```
[super setText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i" arguments:arg] autorelease]];
```

That line was from a 3rd party library so I trying to just get rid of the warning and make it work properly. Anyway how would I fix this warning?

Thanks!

Full method:

```
- (void)timerLoop:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    //update current value
    currentTextNumber += currentStep;

    //check if the timer needs to be disabled
    if ( (currentStep >= 0 && currentTextNumber >= textNumber) || (currentStep < 0 && currentTextNumber <= textNumber) ) {
        currentTextNumber = textNumber;
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }

    //update the label using the specified format
    int value = (int)currentTextNumber;
    int *arg = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    memcpy(arg, &value, sizeof(int));
    //call the superclass to show the appropriate text
    [super setText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i" arguments:arg] autorelease]];
    free(arg);
}
```

Comment: What (data) type of variable is `currentTextNumber`?

Comment: currentTextNumber is a float

Comment: That is really bizarre code.  Someone didn't understand Objective-C very well.

Comment: BTW - If this code is typical in the 3rd party library you are using, I'd strongly consider finding another library.

Comment: I agree but for the most part this library is just pretty much an animating text effect on a UILabel and thats it so its pretty good for the most part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not change it to:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", arg];
[super setText:text];
```

This assumes that `arg` has a type of `int`.

You would only use `initWithFormat:arguments:` if `arg` is actually is a `va_list` from a variable argument list.

Update: Based on the updated code you posted you can do:

```
- (void)timerLoop:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    //update current value
    currentTextNumber += currentStep;

    //check if the timer needs to be disabled
    if ( (currentStep >= 0 && currentTextNumber >= textNumber) || (currentStep < 0 && currentTextNumber <= textNumber) ) {
        currentTextNumber = textNumber;
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }

    //update the label using the specified format
    int value = (int)currentTextNumber;
    [super setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value]];
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know. I am just trying to follow the original code (which I posted above) to make sure it functions the way it was intended to be.

Comment: Thanks! I know I could have definitely done that from the beginning but what do you think was the point of the formatting that the library was using before? I didn't know if it was important or not, which led me to ask this question!

Comment: The original code makes no sense. There is no point to the convoluted creation of the string from a simple `int`.